# visual studio 2015, resharper, razor and formatting embedded html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am running visual studio 2015 with resharper with an mvc application.  I have a View in which I want to create a set of nested `div` tags, a la:

```
<div>
    <label>...
    <div>
        <label>...
        <label>...
        <label>...
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label>...
            <label>...
        </div>
        <label>...
        <label>...
    </div>
</div>
```

I have code like

```
<div class="content">
    @{
        var count = 0;
        var depthList = new Stack<int>();

        <text>
            <div class="NestedSelect">
        </text>

    foreach (var category in Model.OrderBy(m => m.LeftLink)) {
        if (depthList.Count == 0) {
            depthList.Push(category.Depth);

            <text>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="categories" value="@category.Id"><span>@category.Name</span>
                </label>
            </text>
        } else if (category.Depth > depthList.Peek()) {
            depthList.Push(category.Depth);

            <text>
                <div>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="categories" value="@category.Id"><span>@category.Name</span>
                </label>
            </text>
        } else if (category.Depth == depthList.Peek()) {
            <text>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="categories" value="@category.Id"><span>@category.Name</span>
                </label>
            </text>
        } else {
            while (category.Depth < depthList.Peek()) {
        depthList.Pop();
    //@@@@
    <text>
</div>
    </text>
                }

                <text>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="categories" value="@category.Id"><span>@category.Name</span>
                    </label>

                </text>
            }
            //@@@@
            <text>
                </div>
    </text>

            count++;

            if (count == 0) {
            }
        }
    }
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Notice the wonky `<text></div></text>` blocks (marked with `//@@@@`) inside the loop.  VS and/or resharper are very put out that my closing `div` tags do not seem to have mates.  The opening `<text>` tags are highlighted in the editor but the ending `</text>` tags are not.  They have an error underline and the tooltip "End tag is missing matching start tag".

I have tried using the `@:` constructs but when the code is formatted it puts the `@:` on a line by itself and then gets confused with the naked html tags.

How does one build nested html structures with this?

Answer (score 1):

The @: construct should be used here as you suggested,but only on the  tags that are causing the issue.

try something like this:

```
<div class="content">
@{
    var count = 0;
    var depthList = new Stack<int>();

    <text>
        <div class="NestedSelect">
    </text>

    foreach (var category in Model.OrderBy(m => m.LeftLink))
    {
        if (depthList.Count == 0)
        {
            depthList.Push(category.Depth);

            <text>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="categories" value="@category.Id"><span>@category.Name</span>
                </label>
            </text>
        }
        else if (category.Depth > depthList.Peek())
        {
            depthList.Push(category.Depth);

            @:<div>
                <text>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="categories" value="@category.Id"><span>@category.Name</span>
                        </label>
                </text>
        }
        else if (category.Depth == depthList.Peek())
        {
            <text>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="categories" value="@category.Id"><span>@category.Name</span>
                </label>
            </text>
        }
        else
        {
            while (category.Depth < depthList.Peek())
            {
                depthList.Pop();
                @:</div>
            }

            <text>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="categories" value="@category.Id"><span>@category.Name</span>
                </label>

            </text>
        }
            @:</div>

        count++;

        if (count == 0)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That does mostly work, until a resharper "code cleanup".  That still usually puts the `@:` on its own line leaving the would-be escaped tag naked.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@:` construct if you are not obsessed with formatting.

```
@: </div>
```

If you are, consider using [WriteLiteral](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.writeliteral(v=vs.111).aspx) :

```
WriteLiteral("</div>");
```